# Complex XPATH navigation using selenium/python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Basically I'd like to `.click()` the element highlighted here. However, there are multiple of these elements on the page and I'd like to find it based on the text "Media Analyst" slightly higher in the HTML. I have tried many different paths but am not sure how to jump to the parent, move down the html, and then jump in again all with one stroke.

Apologies in advanced for the picture, I'm not sure how to copy direct HTML:

[image]

```
<tr class="lst-hd-rw"></tr>
 <tr id="row_5dd00ba1b1a23d6518f044599a5e42fb" class="ListRow1">
  <td class="ListPrimaryLink lst-cl lst-cl_job_title" style="">
    <a class="ListPrimaryLink" href="?mode=form&id=5dd00ba1b1a23d6518f044599a5e42fb">

        Media Analyst

    </a>
  </td>
<td class="ListPrimaryLink lst-cl lst-cl_visual_id" style=""></td>
<td class="ListPrimaryLink lst-cl lst-cl_job_desc" style=""></td>
<td class="ListPrimaryLink lst-cl lst-cl_onestop_job active_col" style=""></td>
<td class="ListPrimaryLink lst-cl lst-cl_job_type" style=""></td>
<td class="ListPrimaryLink lst-cl lst-cl_major" style=""></td>
<td class="ListPrimaryLink lst-cl lst-cl_job_start" style=""></td>
<td class="ListPrimaryLink lst-cl lst-cl_job_end" style=""></td>
<td class="ListPrimaryLink lst-cl lst-cl_approved" style=""></td>
<td class="ListPrimaryLink lst-cl lst-cl_options lst-cl-last" style="">
    <input class="input-button btn_generic_nav6up" type="button" onclick="self.location.href='?deact=5dd00ba1b1a23d6518f044599a5e42fb&s=jobs&ss=jobs'" value="deactivate"></input>

</td>

</tr>
```

Comment: You should provide the actual `html` here not the image

Comment: Like I said, I don't know how - if you could tell me I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: EDIT: I think I got it

Comment: for the future: if you seek for correct selector you can use SeleniumIDE (Firefox add-on): after clicking on required element IDE will display bunch of available unique selectors (id, xpath, css_selector...), so you can just copy/paste it and use in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea would be to locate the correct `tr` element having the link with "Media Analyst" text:

```
//tr[@class="ListRow1" and contains(td/a, "Media Analyst")]/td/input[@value="deactivate"]
```

Comment: I'm trying to navigate to `class="input-button btn_generic_nav6up"` based on where the Media Analyst text is. Also Media Analyst isn't a link, so neither find_element_by_link_text or partial_link_text would work in this case

Comment: @ik629 it is a link according to the HTML you've posted.

Comment: @ik629 got it. You want to rely on it's text to get to the button. Give me  a second.

Comment: you're right - it is a link, that's my fault for not checking thoroughly